# Million options in React dropdown

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, html-select

Is there a better way to implement million options in dropdown. In my case there can be more than one million users and I need to select one user at a time. I have one choice, make asynchronous call for each letter when typing and I can filter the users. Is there any other methods to implement? If I bind all the options to dropdown, will it make my app slow?

Comment: You answered yourself already, first option you explained looks the only one, so a call every time you type a new character. If you wanna pre fill your drop-down with millions of options, just try yourself and see the reaction of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways. One is what you already said yourself. Making async calls. Or you can also do it a simpler way, This will still have a huge performance boost. It is still not very advisable to filter on the client-side for a million items. But nonetheless, it's possible and I haven't seen any major performance hit.

1. Use a state variable to maintain what you are going to render and another static variable to maintain your entire million collection.
2. On search, you filter that one million list and assign it to the state variable.

3. Render only the items that are in the state variable.

Tip: Make sure your filter method doesn't return more than say, 1000 items at any moment, this will force the user to enter more characters to search and it will keep the UI smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, having a big list to render will make your app slow as it will have to mount and unmount when the user is typing. Ideally the client should send requests to server by using [debounce](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-debouncing-in-javascript) or something to limit the requests and server should send a paginated response / top X number of users which match the input.